# Pam_tally2 not resetting failures on success

Tags: debian, openvpn, pam

I'm using OpenVPN in combination with PAM for user auth via username/password. I have created a customised PAM file as follows:

```
auth required pam_unix.so shadow nodelay
auth requisite pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup vpn
auth required pam_tally2.so deny=5 lock_time=5 unlock_time=1800 even_deny_root
account required pam_unix.so
```

The PAM module correctly identifies users and authenticates them, allowing only VPN users to connect to the virtual network. The issue is that even though the users manage to successfully connect to the VPN, the tally counter keeps going up instead of resetting to 0 (found out with the help of the pam_tally2 command).

The auth.log doesn't log anything suspicious:

```
pam_succeed_if(openvpn:auth): requirement "user ingroup vpn" was met by user "test_user"
pam_succeed_if(openvpn:auth): requirement "user ingroup vpn" was met by user "test_user"
pam_succeed_if(openvpn:auth): requirement "user ingroup vpn" was met by user "test_user"
pam_succeed_if(openvpn:auth): requirement "user ingroup vpn" was met by user "test_user"
```

Working on Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy).

Did I miss something? Is there a way to force resetting the tally counter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems I was required to add the following line:

```
account required pam_tally2.so
```

Just a side note: negative votes without explanations are the worst. It was obvious that I've written my configuration wrong, no need to downvote me for this unless someone would have been kind enough to point out my mistake.

Comment: I have this line, but still doesn't reset. Anything else that needs to be done?

Comment: How did you discover that this is required ? And did you put it before or after the `pam_unix.so` line ?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 16.04

Expected behavior - Three consecutive login failures will cause the system to lockout the ID.  After 30 seconds, the ID is automatically unlocked.

Edit the `/etc/pam.d/common-account` file.
Add the following line as the first executable line.

```
account required pam_tally2.so
```

Edit the `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` file.
Add the following line (without) as the first executable line.

```
auth required pam_tally2.so deny=3 unlock_time=30
```

Edit the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.
Ensure the following name-value pairs are uncommented/set accordingly.

```
UsePAM yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
```

Comment: Don't know why someone else downvoted this answer. It provides the clearest response I've seen regarding which pam_tally2 entries to place in the various pam.d files.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the order of these lines is very important. Try it as follows;

```
auth required pam_tally2.so deny=5 lock_time=5 unlock_time=1800 even_deny_root
auth required pam_unix.so shadow nodelay
auth requisite pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup vpn
account required pam_unix.so
```